# 'PlotLegend' does not display the correct symbol color

Tags: plotting, color, legending

I am plotting some data points with a legend but `PlotLegend` does not yield the same color as the points have. Where is the mistake?

Here is the result that I obtain: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5yga.png

```
ListPlot[{{0.4, 38}, {0.5,   15}, {0.6, 10}},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"a", "b"},
 PlotMarkers -> {
   Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Blue]], White, Rectangle[]},ImageSize -> (15)]},
  PlotRange -> {{0.3, 0.7}, {0, 100}},
 PlotRangePadding -> {0.05, 2},
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[PointLegend[{"data"}, LegendMarkerSize -> 14, 
    LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 18, FontFamily -> "Arial", 
      Black}], {0.165, 0.215}]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grayish edges in legend markers are caused by the default setting:

```
Legending`LegendDump`$DefaultMarkerStyle
```

> ```
> EdgeForm[Directive[Opacity[0.3`], GrayLevel[0]]]
> ```

You can fix the issue in three different ways:

**1.** Use `EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Opacity[1], Blue]]` instead of `EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Blue]]` to get

[image]

**2.**  Add the option `BaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Opacity[1]]` to `PointLegend`:

```
ListPlot[{{0.4, 38}, {0.5, 15}, {0.6, 10}}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"a", "b"}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Blue]], White, 
     Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> (15)]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.3, 0.7}, {0, 100}}, PlotRangePadding -> {0.05, 2}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[PointLegend[{"data"}, BaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Opacity[1]], 
    LegendMarkerSize -> 14, 
    LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 18, FontFamily -> "Arial", 
      Black}], {0.165, 0.215}]]
```

[image]

**3.** Set the value of `` Legending`LegendDump`$DefaultMarkerStyle `` to `Opacity[1]`:

```
Legending`LegendDump`$DefaultMarkerStyle = Opacity[1]

ListPlot[{{0.4, 38}, {0.5, 15}, {0.6, 10}}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"a", "b"}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Blue]], White, 
     Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> (15)]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.3, 0.7}, {0, 100}}, PlotRangePadding -> {0.05, 2}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[PointLegend[{"data"}, LegendMarkerSize -> 14, 
    LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 18, FontFamily -> "Arial", 
      Black}], {0.165, 0.215}]]
```

[image]